# Resftul API structure, Is userID expected in route if already derived from session token?

Tags: rest, uri

I am currently planning a web API based on the principles of REST. I am using a session token to correct identify what user is making a request (after authentication of course), then determining if that user has access to the given resource.

Assuming the user making the request has a `userID` of `7`, and I am wanting to retrieve a list of only the `presentations` that he can access, would best/proper practice be to:

**1.** Include my `userID` in the route, such as:

`localhost:55555/api/users/7/presentations`

or

**2.** Not include `userID`, such as:

`localhost:55555/api/presentations`

Each `presentation` can be accessed by any number of other users. For this reason I am leaning towards option 2 but would like to know what others think before I finalize the structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very common pattern for REST APIs is to have both:

- a list resource with optional parameters like `/presentation/?by=Alice&since=2013-1-1`,
- object resources like `/presentation/0AFF56E7`.

For presentations, I wouldn't use a composite ID containing the user ID, since it doesn't seem really needed and it would prevent future features like changing the "owner" of the presentation (without changing its ID).

Comment: Keeping resource IDs separate from authentication tokens/IDs is a good way to go. After thinking it through and some further research you are right inline with what I was leaning toward. Thanks!